# IBM APIC Developer Toolkit Installation error on Windows 10

Tags: apiconnect

Getting a error on the  IBM APIC Developer Toolkit Installation error on Windows 10 while trying to update the APIC Developer toolkit on my PC.

1. Using command prompt as Administrator

> npm version -3.10.7
>   node version - 4.6.0

2. I have MS Visual Studio 2013 Community edition and Python 2.7 installed as suggested in the per-requistes
3. I am getting the following memory error-

   ```
   > spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall C:\Users\arindch.WIPRO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apiconnect\node_modules\apiconnect-cli-loopback\node_modules\generator-loopback\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\yeoman-environment\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\external-editor\node_modules\spawn-sync
   > node postinstall

   [                ..] \ postinstall: info lifecycle spawn-sync@1.0.15~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
   <--- Last few GCs --->

    1140330 ms: Scavenge 1387.3 (1458.0) -> 1387.3 (1458.0) MB, 29.0 / 0 ms (+ 0.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
    1141330 ms: Mark-sweep 1387.3 (1458.0) -> 1384.3 (1458.0) MB, 1006.0 / 0 ms (+ 0.0 ms in 1 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms) [last resort gc].
    1142315 ms: Mark-sweep 1384.3 (1458.0) -> 1383.0 (1458.0) MB, 973.9 / 16 ms [last resort gc].


   <--- JS stacktrace --->

   ==== JS stack trace =========================================

   Security context: 00000181FB4B4639 <JS Object>
       1: rimraf_(aka rimraf_) [C:\Users\arindch.WIPRO\AppData\Roaming   \npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:~127] [pc=000002834BA761C7] (this=00000181FB4041B9 <undefined>,p=00000324344B83D9 <String[170]: C:\Users\arindch.WIPRO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apiconnect\node_modules\apiconnect-cli-devapps\node_modules\apiconnect-apim-client\node_modules\lodash\_overArg.js>,options=...

   FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
   ```

Comment: @KamaganahallyJaganatha I am not sure what you are asking. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: My apologies for the incomplete update earlier.  Is this the first time you are trying to install API Connect?  Did you follow the install directions in the IBM API Connect 5.0 Knowledge Center?  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tapim_cli_install.html  If you believe that you have done all the steps, can you please provide the log ~/.apiconnect/apic.log?

Comment: No... i had installed it in the past. I was just trying to upgrade the installation to latest version. I will attach the log shortly

Comment: In my earlier comment, I had provided link to Install instructions and the same page has section *Updating your toolkit installation*.  Please follow the directions in that section and it should work.

Comment: I have followed all those instructions

Comment: @KamaganahallyJaganatha   Can you please tell me the file locations in bit more details. I got a file called 'apic' whose content is as follows-   #!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/apiconnect/bin/cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/apiconnect/bin/cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret

Answer (score 1):

Are you installing from the npmjs.org?
Can you please retry install --no-optional --ignore-script as a temporary workaround for v5040 and see if this helps?
Make sure you npm cache clean
This is not normally required and definitely not in future versions.